# angularjs with absolute positioned elements in page

Tags: angularjs

I got this project where the footer is absolute positioned to the bottom. It looks nice but if I load a page where angular is about to inject some long content the div initially renders at the bottom of my screen then the content is injected and the div remains there even though the page got a lot bigger.

This question is more towards the angular community, I probably can hack it with javascript to recompile the layout somehow but I'm just wondering if there are other possible solutions out there.

Comment: Can you post your CSS for the footer?

Comment: yeah sure: `footer {position: absolute;bottom: 0;right: 0;left: 0;}`

Comment: hmm, maybe set a min-height on your content div to push the footer down regardless of content being there

Comment: that's why position: absolute was invented :) to stop people from doing that. My problem is not the div nor the css, it's the lag between the layout and view content loaded by angularjs

Comment: Well, its something you can solve with just css. I have an angular app with a sticky footer that is working fine regardless of content. What about `position: fixed` rather than absolute? Without knowing layout details and stuff I can just speculate at this point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to have a look at ngCloak, and tag your footer with it while the injected content loads.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak

Comment: doesn't seem to work. the footer is part of the layout so it's `uncloacked` right away since `When Angular encounters this directive during the compilation of the template it deletes the ngCloak element attribute, making the compiled element visible.` so it's parsed much faster then the view itself.

Comment: mmmhh... maybe try to wrap the footer in an angular directive ? It should be created at the same time as the rest of the document... and you could call the link function of the directive to do adjustments to the position.

Comment: I'm gonna try with a directive. I was about to hack into `.position()` with jquery ui but I'll give this a try.

Comment: Not working either. I tried even in the browser console to hit `$('footer').css('position', 'absolute').css('bottom', 0).css('right', 0).css('left', 0);` without relying on css at all and it still renders at the bottom of my screen instead of the bottom of the document so it def. needs a javascript hand because the browser's css is left behind right where the layout was loaded